# Table retrieved from session not shown in page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I have defined an asp:table in design as shown below:

```
    <div class="scroll" style="overflow:visible">
      <asp:Table ID="tblMainReport" runat="server" CellPadding="2" 
           CellSpacing="2" HorizontalAlign="Center" GridLines="Both" Width="100%">
      </asp:Table>
    </div>
```

It is a 4-rows 9-columns table dynamically filled in Code behind and is shown successfully on page. After that another button is clicked on the same page:

```
    <div>
       <asp:Button ID="btnDetailReport" runat="server" Text="Show Detail" 
            OnClick="GetDetailReconciliation" />
    </div>
```

This method results in dynamically created data for a Gridview. The Gridview gets dispalyed, however, the table (tblMainReport) gets disappear. The reason seems to be that table control is not maintained between pages as Stateless.

So I save table in session as below:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table ObjTbl = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table();
ObjTbl = tblMainReport;
Session["tblMyMainReport"] = ObjTbl;
```

and then in button Onclick method (GetDetailReconciliation), I retrieve the table from session as:

```
if (Session["tblMyMainReport"] != null)
{
   tblMainReport = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table)Session["tblMyMainReport"];
   tblMainReport.Visible = true;
   int i = tblMainReport.Rows.Count; string s;
   if (i > 0)
      s = tblMainReport.Rows[3].Cells[1].Text;
 }
```

The variable i and s are showing correct retrieved values. However, the tblMainReport still does not show in the page.

Has someone any idea why is the table not showing even it is retrieved successfully from session?

Comment: Are you using WebForms? And where have you placed the code that saves table in session?

Comment: @BenjaminRay No, its a web application. The code that saves the table in session is at the end of method in which the table is dynamically filled with data.

Comment: This definitely looks like WebForms (which is a tech used for web applications). I don't remember everything off the top of my head, but definitely do not store the web control in the session. It could be that you are not setting the datasource for the table on postback. You need to do it even on IsPostBack = true, or use EnableViewState="true". Read up on web controls, postback, databinding and view state in Asp Net Web Forms.

Comment: Are you using UpdatePanels, or is the page fully reloading every time?

Comment: Well, I changed the code and now using DataTables with presentation in Gridview, The issue of losing data between pages is solved automatically as these controls are persisiting the data during postbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table class in ASP.NET Web Forms won't preserve any of your changes made to it from the code behind, unless you put some effort around restoring its state on each postback.

In an effort to be as close to what you have done so far, you could do the following:

Render tblMainReport inside an asp:PlaceHolder:

```
<div class="scroll" style="overflow: visible">
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="tblMainReportPlaceHolder">
        <asp:Table ID="tblMainReport" runat="server" CellPadding="2"
            CellSpacing="2" HorizontalAlign="Center" GridLines="Both" Width="100%">
        </asp:Table>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
```

Then in your GetDetailReconciliation method, add your saved session instance of tblMainReport to your placeholder:

```
if (Session["tblMyMainReport"] != null)
{
    tblMainReportPlaceHolder.Controls.Clear();
    tblMainReportPlaceHolder.Controls.Add((Control)Session["tblMyMainReport"]);
}
```

This should restore your saved table instance in a way that will allow Web Forms to render it.

Bellow I'm providing a working generic example of this approach:

**Markup**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebSandbox.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button Text="Generate Table" runat="server" ID="generateTableButton" OnClick="generateTableButton_Click" />
            <asp:Button Text="Restore Table" runat="server" ID="restoreTableButton" OnClick="restoreTableButton_Click" />

            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="tblMainReportPlaceHolder">
                <asp:Table ID="tblMainReport" runat="server" CellPadding="2"
                    CellSpacing="2" HorizontalAlign="Center" GridLines="Both" Width="100%">
                </asp:Table>
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebSandbox
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void generateTableButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cell1 = new TableCell
            {
                Text = "Cell 1"
            };

            var cell2 = new TableCell
            {
                Text = "Cell 2"
            };

            var row = new TableRow();
            row.Cells.Add(cell1);
            row.Cells.Add(cell2);

            tblMainReport.Rows.Add(row);

            Session["tblMyMainReport"] = tblMainReport;
        }

        protected void restoreTableButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tblMainReportPlaceHolder.Controls.Clear();
            tblMainReportPlaceHolder.Controls.Add((Control)Session["tblMyMainReport"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just call the logic used to built your table, every time you need it to render.